# How can I round up to the nearest multiple of the specified number?

Tags: java, algorithm, numeric

I've looked at many questions regarding rounding up to the nearest multiple of a number, but I can't understand their methods well enough to adopt them for rounding up to 45 or they use language specific methods of other languages.

Here is a bit more detailed explanation if the above doesn't make much sense yet:

**Example input:**

```
int num1 = 67;
int num2 = 43;
```

**Expected results:**

```
>>round(num1) = 90
>>round(num2) = 45
```

Comment: as in round, floor of ceil?

Comment: `(num + 23)/45*45`?

Comment: Why would 67 round to 90 but not 45?

Comment: Integer division truncates, i.e rounds down, so to round up you simply add `divisor-1` before dividing. Since division and multiplication operators have equal precedence and are executed left-to-right, you can simply divide then multiply to cause truncation. In short, to round up to multiple of 45: `val = (val + 44) / 45 * 45`.

Comment: @kazenorin Because OP wants round-up, not round-nearest.

Comment: If (number modulus 45 != 0) Then number +=     45 - (number modulus 45)

Comment: `num += 44; num -= num % 45;` (so 46 gets 90)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's enough to add the missing `mod45`:

```
int upperround45(int i) {
    int temp = i%45;
    //For the algorithm we wish the rest to be how much more than last multiple of 45.
    if (temp < 0 ) 
        temp = 45 + temp;
    if (temp == 0) {
        return i;
    } else {
        return i + 45 - temp;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In general:

```
int upperround(int num, int base) {
    int temp = num%base;
    if (temp < 0 ) 
        temp = base + temp;
    if (temp == 0) 
        return num;
    return num + base - temp;
```

Comment: Could shorten it using conditional operator `return (temp == 0 ? num : num + base - temp);` and method should be `static`. Also be aware that it cannot handle negative values. Still, up-voted.

Comment: I agree with negatives. I don't use conditional operator when explaining stuff to beginners as it's not that easy for them. At the compilation they're both the same and for reading my version is easier to newbies :)

Thanks for upvoting

Comment: Then for newbies, you shouldn't put `return` on same line as `if`. ;-) Hmmm.... I do guess that my answer doesn't really help newbies understand the intricacies of integer math, huh.

Answer (score 8):

Since people have such trouble with rounding to multiple of an integer number, whether rounding up/down/nearest, here are *very simple* methods for doing so:

```java
public static int roundDown(int value, int multiplier) {
    return value / multiplier * multiplier;
}
public static int roundHalfUp(int value, int multiplier) {
    return (value + multiplier / 2) / multiplier * multiplier;
}
public static int roundUp(int value, int multiplier) {
    return (value + multiplier - 1) / multiplier * multiplier;
}
```

*Test*

```
Value Down Half   Up
    0    0    0    0
    1    0    0    4
    2    0    4    4
    3    0    4    4
    4    4    4    4
```

```
Value Down Half   Up
    0    0    0    0
    1    0    0    5
    2    0    0    5
    3    0    5    5
    4    0    5    5
    5    5    5    5
```

**Negative Numbers**

They don't work right for negative numbers. "Round down" usually means "towards zero", unlike [`Math.floor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) which rounds towards negative infinity.

Here are versions that can handle negative values. These are consistent with the [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) options of similar names used by `BigDecimal`.

```java
public static int roundDown(int value, int multiplier) {
    if (multiplier <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return value / multiplier * multiplier;
}
public static int roundHalfUp(int value, int multiplier) {
    if (multiplier <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return (value + (value < 0 ? multiplier / -2 : multiplier / 2)) / multiplier * multiplier;
}
public static int roundUp(int value, int multiplier) {
    if (multiplier <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return (value + (value < 0 ? 1 - multiplier : multiplier - 1)) / multiplier * multiplier;
}
```

*Test*

```
Value Down Half   Up
   -4   -4   -4   -4
   -3    0   -4   -4
   -2    0   -4   -4
   -1    0    0   -4
    0    0    0    0
    1    0    0    4
    2    0    4    4
    3    0    4    4
    4    4    4    4
```

```
Value Down Half   Up
   -5   -5   -5   -5
   -4    0   -5   -5
   -3    0   -5   -5
   -2    0    0   -5
   -1    0    0   -5
    0    0    0    0
    1    0    0    5
    2    0    0    5
    3    0    5    5
    4    0    5    5
    5    5    5    5
```

Comment: Very nice answer !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is the following

```
public static int round(int num) {
    return num - num % 45 + (num%45==0? 0 : 45);
}
```

---

### [Tested](http://ideone.com/SeQc2u)

```
int num1 = 67;
int num2 = 43;
int num3 = 90;

System.out.println(num1 - num1 % 45 + (num1%45==0? 0 : 45)); // 90
System.out.println(num2 - num2 % 45 + (num2%45==0? 0 : 45)); // 45
System.out.println(num3 - num3 % 45 + (num3%45==0? 0 : 45)); // 90
```