# Always round up to ten in Java

Tags: java

I haven't found any answer of this. But I want to round up to ten of any number. Like this:

```
32 -> 40
25 -> 30
88 -> 90
```

But with this code below I get rounded down. How can I always round up and not to the nearest ten?

```
Math.round(number / 10.0) * 10;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117380/5221149) to another question for how to handle negative numbers.*

To round down to nearest multiple of 10, simply divide by 10 and multiply by 10, using the fact that integer division always rounds down (towards zero).

```
roundDown = value / 10 * 10;
```

To round up, add 9 before rounding down.

```
roundUp = (value + 9) / 10 * 10;
```

To round half-up, add 5 before rounding down.

```
roundHalfUp = (value + 5) / 10 * 10;
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println("    Down  Up  Half-Up");
int[] arr = { 32, 25, 88, 50 };
for (int v : arr)
    System.out.printf("%2d %4d %4d %5d%n", v, v / 10 * 10, (v + 9) / 10 * 10, (v + 6) / 10 * 10);
```

*Output*

```
    Down  Up  Half-Up
32   30   40    30
25   20   30    30
88   80   90    90
50   50   50    50
```

Answer (score 2):

`round` may round up or down, depending on the remainder. Instead, you should use [`ceil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-):

```
Math.ceil(number / 10.0) * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you want a value plus the difference from ten of the remainder. You can get the remainder with `%` (modulus). Like,

```
int[] arr = { 32, 25, 88 };
for (int v : arr) {
    System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", v, v + (10 - (v % 10)));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
32 -> 40
25 -> 30
88 -> 90
```

You said ***always*** rounding up. If ninety should stay ninety, then you test for a remainder of zero. Like,

```
for (int v : arr) {
    int r = v % 10;
    if (r != 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", v, v + 10 - r);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", v, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: 90 -> 100

Comment: @Andreas Fair enough. But OP said always rounding up. Added an addendum.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using only Java integer arithmetic with this:

```
x % 10 == 0 ? x : ((x / 10)  + 1) * 10
```

so:

```
int x = 41;
int r = x % 10 == 0 ? x : ((x / 10)  + 1) * 10;
System.out.println(r);
```

will print:

```
50
```